# Laravel Spark Next Hangs At Pending Subcription

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I have set up laravel spark next and jetsream with inertia as the base for authentication purposes. I have also acquired myself a paddle sandbox account to set up billing. I have successfully set up a subscription plan through paddle to test. After setting up the required env variables for paddle I proceeded to sign up to the service through the /billing endpoint. I enter the sandbox details in the payment gateway I enter the paddle interface as a subscriber so i know the api is working well. Unfortunately the subscription never applies to the user account. All it does is hangs at Subscription Pending.... After inspecting the network it appears that the billing url is stuck in an endless loop. I have followed everything to a tee. Is there something I am missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: HAve you solved it? I seems cant find the way to solve it

Answer (score 2):

To handle subscription events, you need to configure webhooks in your Paddle account. You can refer to the [Spark's documentation for webhooks](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.x/spark-paddle/configuration.html#paddle-webhooks).

As for enabling webhooks for your local environment, you can also [refer to the documentation](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.x/spark-paddle/configuration.html#webhooks-local-development).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your .env file does not contain any leading spaces in the lines where you paste in your public key from Paddle. For example, it should read:

```
PADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIICIjANBgk...AAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

And not:

```
PADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
                   MIICIjANBgk...AAQ
                   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

This took me way too long to catch.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem just now. My issue was that I didn't set the STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET in the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error, I've dig further, and for me it was on the Paddle (payment gateway) side, using their Webhook simulator, it allows me to understand that they expect from your end to have a **SSL Certificate that disclose the full chain**.

Meaning that, depending on how you install your certificate on your website, you should provide your public certificate and the CA-bundle file (A file where there are many certificates on top of each other).

Here a site where you can discover if you have a **chain issue**

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

*Additional note for Traefik users (Docker reverse proxy):*

Yes Traefik is able to handle a 1 file certificate where you put your certificate **on top** of the certificate inside the CA-bundle.